# Stop alertCtrl auto triggering cancel in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, alert

I've got an alert controller that, when triggered, opens and then immediately closes without me doing anything.

```
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Requires Login',
    message: 'Please register or log in to add to cart.',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Login',
        handler: () => {
          this.logOut();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
```

I can't find anything wrong and I'm wondering what is causing this issue? When I run the application through my phone I get the error, but when I run it through the browser, no error.

Comment: Occur only on phone?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa yes only on the phone

Comment: try adding `role: 'cancel'` to cancel button. It should be `text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel', handler: .........`

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa same issue even if I have that.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa yes.

Comment: Worked.? Did you try devtool any error?

Comment: Try to see if OnDidDismiss is fired on the alert

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example from my current project

```
logout() {
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Confirm',
  message: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'No',
      handler: () => { }
    },
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      handler: () => {
        this.removeNotificationRegistrationAndLogOut(LoginPage, true);
      }
    }
  ]
});
confirm.present();
}
```